# Windows: Access or Mount an FTP Server in Read-Only Mode?

Tags: windows, ftp

I would like an application for Windows that will allow me read-only access to an ftp server that has full read/write/delete access.

The FTP server is not one which I can administer or control  - I would like to a client-side protection to prevent accidentally deleting or uploading files to the server.

chmod is not acceptable solution as it requires initially making modifications that will affect other people or other applications

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have no control over the FTP server, but you somehow can force your users to access that FTP server only through a client software authorized by you?

Comment: I won't be forcing the users. The incentive for them to follow instructions is to not accidentally delete their own work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have other special requirements (such as SFTP / FTPS support) about any web browser will do.

Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer all have a built-in FTP client that allows read-only access to FTP sites, although there are [plans](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333943) to remove it from Chrome. (A similar request to remove FTP support from Firefox was [declined](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1174462).).

Simply try visiting [any FTP site](ftp://cdimage.debian.org/) to see if your browser supports it.